# Cannot install tensorflow with error EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am new to python so I am not using any environment, all I am doing is trying to install tensorflow using pip and getting the following:

```
> pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (342.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.33.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.35.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.25.11)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2020.11.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\teren\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\teren\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

The pip version is 20.2.4 and the python version is 3.8.
I am using Windows 10 so I am not sure if this is a windows thing.

I see that the pip is using a cached package so I tried

```
pip --no-cache-dir install tensorflow
```

but I still get

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\teren\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an environment which is recommended by tensorflow community
Please follow the following link
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
Please ensure you follow this document step by step

Incase if you feel that its a lot of manual work then use Anaconda navigator
Click on Environments tab create Environment named tensorflow and then on to right download all packages which you need to install

Once done click on your new environment and launch jupyter notebook

Comment: In the answer by Rishabh, if you use Anaconda, when you create the new environment select python 3.7 not 3.8. Apparently Anaconda  has a problem when you try to use 3.8 with tensorflow.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with missing files during pip install on Windows happens when the path is too long.

You can fix this by using regedit, going to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem and changing the value of LongPathsEnabled to 1.

Comment: I've already done this, but I'm still getting the issue.